# Why is it necessary to return item in pipelines.py in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

The pipelines.py send data parsed  into database or file or json. pipelines, from scrapy's architecture overview ,there are 9 steps ,step 1-8 constitute a whole loop,step 9 create a new process which contains 8 other same processes such like previous.

[image]

In some sample pipelines.py,we often see such codes as below:

```
import pymysql.cursors
class MySQLPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect = pymysql.connect(
            host='127.0.0.1',  
            port=3306,  
            db='xxxx',  
            user='root',  
            passwd='xxxx',  
            charset='utf8',  
            use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.connect.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("sql_insert_command")
        self.connect.commit()
        return item
```

`pipelines.py` is the last step in a whole 8 processes,why `return item` in pipelines.py after send item into database or other storage way?
`item` had been insert into database,it is no use to call the `item` by any component in scrapy again?
I have tested `return item` can't be omitted,want to know why?

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy supports multiple pipelines being enabled simultaneously.

That is why it is important that pipelines pass items forward, unless they are pipelines that are specifically crafted to drop certain items.

For example, you could later decide to add a second pipeline that stores items locally, in addition to storing them in the database.

Answer (score 0):

From [documntation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#process_item):

> This method is called for every item pipeline component.
>   process_item() must either: return a dict with data, return an Item
>   (or any descendant class) object, return a Twisted Deferred or raise
>   DropItem exception. Dropped items are no longer processed by further
>   pipeline components.